# Find the value of: $\sum_{n=1}^{50}n(n!)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the value of the summation:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{50}n(n!)$$

The solution in the answer key is $51!-1$. I am unable to find the given solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a telescoping sum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{50}n\cdot n!$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704998/evaluate-sum-n-150n-cdot-n)

Answer (score 14):

Hint

- Use $n \cdot n! = (n+1 - 1) \cdot n! = (n+1)! - n!$

Comment: In case anyone cares:  $1551118753287382280224243016469303211063259720016986111999999999999$

Answer (score 2):

Note that with just a little experimentation you can guess the result. Calculate

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot k!$$

for $n=1,2,3$, and $4$, and you get $1,5,23$, and $119$. If necessary, you can go one step further and for $n=5$ get $719$. Those numbers should be recognizable as $2!-1,3!-1,4!-1,5!-1$, and $6!-1$. Now even if you don’t see the telescoping trick, you can guess that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot k!=(n+1)!-1$$

and try to prove it by induction, something that turns out to be very easy.